# Git: How Can I get back to my MASTER without committing?

Tags: git

My `master` branch is messed. I should have setup branches before now, but I've just realized why I need them!

So, I've got a pile of changes in `master` that I don't want to commit yet, but I've got some hotfix stuff in a new branch that I want to commit.

How can I put all that stuff in `master` aside and push a tiny hotfix from a branch?

Basically, I'm not ready to push any of the stuff in the screenshot live yet:

[image: Overview of Git Main Branch]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`git stash`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html)

```
DESCRIPTION
       Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working
       directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working
       directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts
       the working directory to match the HEAD commit.
```

You can also then

```
git stash list
```

will show all the stashes you've made, and

```
git stash clear
```

if you'd like to just abandon the stashed changes.

Comment: git stash is an easy way to temporarily store uncomitted changes. Although you might also just commit the changes, and undo the commit later again to finish it.

Answer (score 1):

As of Git 2.5 (July 2015), you can use [git worktree](http://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows):

```
git worktree add -b patch-1 ../patch-1
```

This is essentially just creating a branch, but it puts the new branch into a
new folder alongside the parent repo. This is nice because you can do work on
this branch, even without committing, then switch back to master with a clean
working directory.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but couldn't you just REVERT your master back to a less screwy time, then commit your hotfix changes. If I understand you, that's what I'd do.

Comment: This is not really relevant for the problem at hand.